# How can I choose Gaussian Elimination to solve Ax=b in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a question about solving linear equation `Ax=b`, in which `x` is unknown, A is square matrix `NxN` and non-singular matrix.

The vector `x` can be solved by

```
x=inv(A)*b
```

or

```
x=A\b
```

In Matlab, the ‘\’ command invokes an algorithm which depends upon the structure of the matrix A and includes checks (small overhead) on properties of A. Hence, It highly depends on A structure. However, A structure is unknown (i.e random matrix). I want to measure complexity of above equation. Hence, to fairly comparison, I need to fixed the method which I used. In this case, I choose Gaussian Elimination (GE) with complexity `O(N^3)` My question is how can I choose/fix the method (i.e. GE) to solve above equation?

Comment: There is no MATLAB built-in function that solves a linear system with Gaussian elimination. But a self-written function is always going to be slower than the highly optimized '\' operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to compute the LU factorisation (assuming A is not symmetric)

```
[L,U] = lu(A)
```

where L is a permutation of a lower-triangular matrix with unit diagonal and U is upper triangular. This is equivalent to the Gaussian elimination.
Then, when you solve Ax = b, you actually perform first Ly = b and then Ux = y.
The important thing is that solving these linear system is essentially O(n^2), while computing the factorisation is O(n^3). So if n is big, you can just measure the time taken to compute the LU factorisation.

---

For random matrices, you can see the complexity of the LU factorization like that

```
nn = round(logspace(2, 4, 20)) ;
time = zeros(size(nn)) ;
for i = 1:numel(nn)
    A = rand(nn(i),nn(i)) ;
    tic() ; [L,U] = lu(A) ;
    time(i) = toc() ;
end
loglog(nn,time) ;
```

(change the "4" to something bigger or smaller, depending on you pc).
On my laptop, I have this result

[image]

where the slop of 3 (hence, the O(n^3) complexity) is fairly clear.

Comment: So, what is solution of x if I use LU

Comment: You will have x = U \ ( L \ b ).

Comment: If my matrix A is symmetric matrix. So, your method will noe work, Is it right? How can I check the A whether symmetric or non-symmetric? Thank

Comment: If `A` is symmetric, then the transpose of `A` is equal to itself.  Perhaps something like `Ap = A(:); App = reshape(A.',[],1); issymmetric = all(abs(A - Ap) <= 1e-10);` may work.  However, LU decomposition is immaterial on whether or not `A` is symmetric.  LU decomposition works on a square matrix regardless of its contents... what you will actually get from LU is another story, but you are able to still factor it into LU.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thank you. Do you know how can I choose Gaussian Elimination in Matlab? It looks like inv(A)*V?

Comment: Never use `inv` ever. It is unstable. Gaussian elimination is not available in MATLAB on purpose because it's an inefficient algorithm. The closest you can achieve is with LU as seen above.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks. For small matrix as 10 by 10, 20 by 20, or 30 by 30, Do you think LU can show the exact O(n^2) complexity in MATLAB? I will use LU and measure the complexity over and. Then plot it by timeit to show fitting graph between simulation and theory

Comment: The complexity of LU is O(n^3). And 30 x 30 will most likely be to small :'( You should use bigger matrices. And a good thing to do is to make a log-log plot with time with respect to the matrix size (n), with n = 10, 100, 1000, 10 000, 100 000, 1 000 000, etc. You should see a slop of 3 in the log-log plot.

Comment: @leo: It means the yaxis will be use log scale. Could you show it by give us a example with random matrix?